# AngularJS directive - complex directive name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

We started to use the AngularJS in the project that supposed to be large and decided to use "modular" project structure and naming conventions. Everything is works good, except directives.

Our naming conventions for angular components is the following:
`App.Module.Component.Name`

So when I register the directive, it looks like `App.Module.directive("App.Module.Directives.DataViewer",function(){...});`

The problem with directive, that now I don't know how to use it in DOM.
When I restrict the directive to "A" and write HTML `<div App.Module.Directives.DataViewer></div>`, then when it parsed by browser the attribute is lower case and directive doesn't work.

If I restrict "C", and HTML `<div class="App.Module.Directives.DataViewer"></div>`, I don't know why, but the directive still not works. The only way I succeed to use the directive, is camelCase or using all lower case for attribute, or only camelCase on class. Is there any solution for this?

We are not considering "E" directive, because of IE8 compatibility.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capital's are automatically camel cased for safe use within HTML (HTML is case insensitive which can lead to confusion so the standard is to use only lowercase for HTML attributes) (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

So

```
App.Module.directive("app.Module.Directives.DataViewer",function(){...});
```

Can be reference like so:

```
<div app.-module.-directives.-dataViewer></div>
```

Note that I lower cased your first letter in "app"

Comment: adding unnecessary dots  in html due to poor conventions scares me

Comment: I certainly wouldn't recommend this naming scheme and I like your approach (+1) but I know how companies can force naming schemes for all manner of reasons- so in case he's stuck...

Comment: Thanks!! It works with attribute. I agree with @charlietfl that the HTML looks ugly now, but at least this is work. Is it possible to workaround such case for "class" with restriction "C" ? And as I understand, there no way to workaround first letter to be capital?

Comment: I just tested to be sure and no "C" operates exactly the same way- only supporting camel cased.

Comment: would make sure that your dot convention works cross all browsers. I know in jQuery have to use escaping of dots within selectors...which could be a pain point within your directives

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, I think it's can be a kind of pain to maintenance such things. It may not work with css and jQuery...so I will present it to our CTO and he will decide if he wants such headaches :)

Comment: right...consider it in case of using as class, adding dots in class will be very problematic

Answer (score 2):

Should probably consider creating modules for various parts of the app.

You only use one module to initalize page, one that matches `ng-app`. Howver you can have as many modules as you want, and inject those in main `ng-app` module

```
angular.module('App.Module.Component.Name',[])
/* use camelCase for directives*/
.directive('componentNameDataviewer',function....;
```

Then in markup:

```
<div component-name-dataviewer></div>
```

Then inject module within main `ng-app` module

```
var app=angular.module('myApp',['App.Module.Component.Name']);
```

Could have modules who's only purpose is to consolidate the injections also such as modules that only contain directives, or modules that only contain filters, or services

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately in our case we doesn't have single ng-app. We have "standalone" applications on same page that manually bootstrapped. The problem with your suggestion is that we can have two directives with the same name in different modules, so if both modules are registered within application, we cannot use both of the directives.

Comment: We not have ng-app on page at all. We have something like: angluar.bootstrap(app1Element,["App1"]);angluar.bootstrap(app2Element,["App2"]); Each application has it's own modules.

Comment: right...realized what you were saying.... still think your dot notation will come back to bite in markup though